# Undefined index: user_image in

Tags: php

I am using this code upload image on server. And bulid API using this code on PHP

```
 $mysql = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME) or die('Unable to connect');


//An array to display the response
$response = array();
if ($mysql-> connect_error){
    $response["MESSAGE"]="ERROR IN SERVER";
    $response["STATUS"]=500;

}else{
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["user_image"]["tmp_name"])&& @$_POST["user_name"]){

        $tmp_file= $_FILES["user_image"]["tmp_name"];
        $img_name= $_FILES["user_image"]["name"];
        $upload_dir="./images".$img_name;
            $sql= "INSERT INTO image (user_name,user_profile) VALUES ('{$_POST['user_name']}','{$img_name}')";
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_file,$upload_dir)&& $mysql -> query($sql)){
                    $response["MESSAGE"]="FILE UPLOADE";
                    $response["STATUS"]=200;

            }
            else{
                $response["MESSAGE"]="FAILED";
                $response["STATUS"]=404;
            }
            }
            else{
                $response["MESSAGE"]="INVALID REQUEST";
                    $response["STATUS"]=400;
            }
        }
            echo  json_encode($response);
```

Comment: can you post form upload?

Answer (score 0):

You don't post the form. Maybe you forget to add the enctype attribue on the form element :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' name='user_image'>
</form>
```